# What is <li> in html. how it is different from <div>

Tags: java, html, selenium

I am trying to identify the elements to use in Selenium. Just curious to understand What is `<li>` tag in HTML.

How it is different from `<div>`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

li is a list item in either an unordered list ul or ordered list ol (a list with numbers)

Check out this for more info:

https://www.w3schools.com/html/html_lists.asp

And a div is essentially a divided/separated area of your page where you can stylize using CSS or manipulate using JS.